# Database or storage method for json data

Tags: json, database

I'm working to store json data. The data will be:

1. For each user, let's estimate 5000+
2. Large, up to a few megabytes
3. Updated frequently, up to 1000 times a day

There are 2 special cases here:

A. The data will usually be mostly the same. 98% of the time changes to the json data will only be a 1-2% different from the existing data.

B. The json schema is not set. Occasionally keys will change names, may have different data, or will cease to exist. This accounts for some of the "large" changes not included in (A).

My main concern is point (3) above. I have knowledge in mysql. Is there any storage medium that will allow me to do partial updates to the large, possibly not-set, dataset? This will allow the user to send smaller amounts of data, and hopefully make the db updates more efficient.

Comment: Did you think to split your JSON array into a PHP array (if you use PHP) to create as many columns in MySQL there are columns in your original table?

Comment: I suppose that would be a partial solution. How would it handle part (B) in my post? What happens if some users update and use a new schema (column names) and the other have not yet updated to this new format?